# Why java socket doesn't set its "closed" status to be true when it encounter an "connection reset" exception ?

Tags: java, tcp

Why java socket doesn't set its "closed" status to be true when it encounter an "connection reset" exception? And also set the `isConnected` to be false, `isInputShutdown` & `isOutputShutdown` to be true? It seems the `socket` is unavailable at this moment. Is it the specification of the tcp protocal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on Stack Overflow is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In general "why" questions can only be answered by the original developers. But are you sure you understand what the "connection reset" exception means?